# How to ignore path when extracting zip file in python

Tags: python, path, zip

I want to ignore the path of a file stored in a zip. 
I use the following:

```
ZipFile.extract('/ignorepath/filename.txt', '/mygoodpath')
```

This will create the followng:

> /mygoodpath/ignorepath/filename.txt

I would prefer

> /mygoodpath/filename.txt

I am looking at shutil.move as well as ZipFile.open to open and write, though the later would probably have a few edge cases. Best method to handle this?

Comment: 'ZipExtFile' does not support the buffer interface ... of course, specialized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [Zipfile.open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open)

```
with ZipFile('spam.zip') as myzip:
    with myzip.open('/ignorepath/filename.txt') as infile:
        with open('/mygoodpath/filename.txt', 'w') as outfile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())
```

Comment: if there are also binary files, just add b option